# C++ Close window not application

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create two instances of a window class.
When the primary one is closed it should close the application but when the secondary one is closed it should just close that window.

However when either window is closed the application exits, and I'm not sure why. I've tried comparing the hWnd to check which window is being closed.

```
// include the basic windows header file
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

//Forgive me now
#define MAX_WINDOWS 1024

HWND hWindows[MAX_WINDOWS];

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd,
    UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam);

// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWindows[0] = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        L"WindowClass1",    // name of the window class
        L"Our First Windowed Program",   // title of the window
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    // window style
        300,    // x-position of the window
        300,    // y-position of the window
        500,    // width of the window
        400,    // height of the window
        NULL,    // we have no parent window, NULL
        NULL,    // we aren't using menus, NULL
        hInstance,    // application handle
        NULL);    // used with multiple windows, NULL

    hWindows[1] = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        L"WindowClass1",    // name of the window class
        L"Our First Windowed Program",   // title of the window
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    // window style
        300,    // x-position of the window
        300,    // y-position of the window
        500,    // width of the window
        400,    // height of the window
        hWindows[0],    // primary window
        NULL,    // we aren't using menus, NULL
        hInstance,    // application handle
        NULL);    // used with multiple windows, NULL

    ShowWindow(hWindows[0], nCmdShow);
    ShowWindow(hWindows[1], nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        // translate keystroke messages into the right format
        TranslateMessage(&msg);

        // send the message to the WindowProc function
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // return this part of the WM_QUIT message to Windows
    return msg.wParam;
}

// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // sort through and find what code to run for the message given
    switch (message)
    {

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            if (hWnd = hWindows[0]) {
                // close the application entirely
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
            else {
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            }
            return 0;
        } break;

    }

    // Handle any messages the switch statement didn't
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (hWnd = hWindows[0])
```

That's assignment. Since `hWindows[0]` is non-zero, that expression always evaluates true.

You mean:

```
if (hWnd == hWindows[0])
```

You should call `PostQuitMessage` in response to `WM_DESTROY`. And since the default window procedure calls `DestroyWindow` in response to `WM_CLOSE`, you can write it like this:

```
switch (message)
{
case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        if (hWnd == hWindows[0]) {
            // close the application entirely
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    break;
}

// Handle any messages the switch statement didn't
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
```